# "Easy" Example for a non metric topology on $R^n$

Tags: general-topology

I am working through Allen Hatchers Basic Point-Set Topology Notes: (http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Top/TopNotes.pdf) and as he introduced the basis of a topology and set remarks on how a basis topology could be done on $R^n$ with open balls. It got me thinking how i can define a simple non metric topology on $R^n$, where i can also find a basis for the topology. (Apart from open disks and open intervals of course).

EDIT: it should not be the trivial Topology with $\{\varnothing,R^n\}$. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: The trivial topology has basis $\{\varnothing , \mathbb R^n \}$.

Comment: It suffices to find any non separated topology. The one given by Rudy works fine

Comment: What is "a basis topology"?

Comment: i meant basis for a topology. i will fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of these:

- The trivial topology.
- OK, you ruled that out - the "almost trivial topology" $\{\emptyset, \{(0, .., 0)\}, \mathbb{R}^n\}$.
- In general, any *non-$T_0$* topology will do the job (and that's massive overkill).
- The cofinite topology.
- The cocountable topology.

And plenty of others. Not only are these not defined *in terms of* a metric, they don't correspond to *any possible* metric - they are **non-metrizable topologies**.

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$ with one of these topologies is the same as $\Bbb R^m$ with that topology, so they are sort of "boring" in that way. The Zariski topology on $\mathbb R^n$, which has as basis the complements of the zero sets of n-variate polynomials is maybe more interesting in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

You should note that any topology is trivially a basis for itself, so you just need to find an example of a non-metrizable topology (and there are many of these).

However, for a somewhat interesting example that's probably closer to what you had in mind, try a basis consisting of elements of the form $[a_1,b_1)\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n)$ for $a_i,b_i\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Please Alex, could you add a proof that it is not metrizable?